# Expected DTD markup was not found caused by US Gov Website down?

Tags: xml, dtd

I am trying to upload an XML document into a database for metadata. I've been using this XML for a number of years now as a template. I've never had any issues with it until recently.

When I upload, I keep getting an error:

> Expected DTD markup was not found. Line 1, position 3.

I don't have a lot of XML experience, but the header in the XML reads like this:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><!DOCTYPE metadata SYSTEM "http://www.fgdc.gov/metadata/fgdc-std-001-1998.dtd"><metadata>
```

I clicked on the link and it takes me to the USGS.gov website. An intro page tells me that the USGS website is down due to the ongoing federal government shutdown. I'm wondering if any of you XML guru's out there can tell me if that website needs to be active in order for my XML to read the DTD from it? IF I am right in saying that, is there a possible workaround?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I hate to answer my own question so quickly, but I think I figured out the problem.

The first line of the XML reads as this:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><!DOCTYPE metadata SYSTEM "http://www.fgdc.gov/metadata/fgdc-std-001-1998.dtd"><metadata>
```

Turns out the fgdc website link in that line is referenced to the USGS.gov website. That website is down right now because of the US federal government shutdown. I believe the XML is trying to reference the DTD markup from that site and because the website is down, it's breaking the reference.

I found a copy of the fgdc-std-001-1998.dtd [here](https://github.com/okfn/ckanext-spatial/blob/master/ckanext/spatial/validation/xml/fgdc/fgdc-std-001-1998.dtd) :

I copied and pasted the markup into an xml editor, saved it as the same name on my local drive and changed the reference in the xml. This seems to work fine.